# print only the pattern in the whole line using grep

Tags: regex, awk, grep, gawk

As i know to print only the pattern using command grep -o.
i have a file like this:

```
Job <472971> Job Name <aaaaaaaaaaa> User <bbbbbbbbb> Project <cccccc> Status <RUN> Queue <AL_Ptime>Interactive pseudo-terminal shell mode Submitted from host <lsf_login07> CWD </asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>
```

i want to print out all the pattern inside `< >` , my desire output look like this:

```
<472971> <aaaaaaaaaaa> <bbbbbbbbb> <cccccc> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> <lsf_login07> </asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>
```

I tried a lot but i can print out exactly pattern `< >`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `grep -oE '<[^>]+>'`:

```
$ echo "Job <472971> Job Name <aaaaaaaaaaa> User <bbbbbbbbb> Project <cccccc> Status <RUN> Queue <AL_Ptime>Interactive pseudo-terminal shell mode Submitted from host <lsf_login07> CWD </asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>" \
| grep -oE '<[^>]+>'
<472971>
<aaaaaaaaaaa>
<bbbbbbbbb>
<cccccc>
<RUN>
<AL_Ptime>
<lsf_login07>
</asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>
```

If you want to get rid of the newlines and have spaces in between, you can pipe this into a simple **awk** like this:

```
grep -oE '<[^>]+>' |  awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR==1?"":" "), $0}'
```

or with **tr**:

```
grep -oE '<[^>]+>' | tr "\n" " "
```

EDIT:
Suppose OP uses an input file with a number of these lines, one could turn to GNU **awk**:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FPAT="<[^>]+>" }
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", (i==1?"":" "), $i
  printf "\n"
}
```

Using it:

```
awk -f tst.awk file
```

where file is:

```
$ cat file
Job <472971> Job Name <aaaaaaaaaaa> User <bbbbbbbbb> Project <cccccc> Status <RUN> Queue <AL_Ptime>Interactive pseudo-terminal shell mode Submitted from host <lsf_login07> CWD </asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>
Job <472971> Job Name <aaaaaaaaaaa> User <bbbbbbbbb> Project <cccccc> Status <RUN> Queue <AL_Ptime>Interactive pseudo-terminal shell mode Submitted from host <lsf_login07> CWD </asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="<[^>]+>"} \
        {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", (i==1?"":" "), $i; printf "\n"}' file
<472971> <aaaaaaaaaaa> <bbbbbbbbb> <cccccc> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> <lsf_login07> </asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>
<472971> <aaaaaaaaaaa> <bbbbbbbbb> <cccccc> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> <lsf_login07> </asdfghjklll/dsadasd/asda>
```

Comment: tks Marc it's work. But i have another problem 
i have many line that in file, which contain many Jobs
so that output will have many line too, there for the awk command doesn't work well
i wondering my output can have many line like my desire output?

Comment: Added solution to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Marc
if i using that awk file do i have to use grep command? Because if i just only use the awk file that the output just look like the input file.
Or the input file of that awk file is the output file after using grep command? 
i tried both but it doesn't work as well

Comment: No, you don't have to use grep with that. Check if you have GNU awk installed.

Comment: oh no 
i try it again with using my simple input on the question and your code work perfectly
i just don't know why it doesn't work with my real input.

Comment: Is that input file somehow different from the input line in the question? Just cut and paste 2 lines to show me.

Comment: to change multiple lines to single, use paste... for ex: `seq 5 | paste -sd' '`

Comment: Job <472971> Job Name <abce> User <Lucil> Project <SV> Status <RUN> Queue <AL_Ptime>Interactive pseudo-terminal shell mode Command </asdfghjk>Wed Nov  1 13:50:57: Submitted from host <lsf_login07> CWD </asdfgh> 6 Processors Requested
Job <456750> Job Name <dasd> User <Lucil> Project <SV> Status <EXIT> Queue <AL_Other> Interactive pseudo-terminal shell mode Command </asdasdasd>Tue Oct 31 18:03:38: Submitted from host <lsf_login07> CWD </csadas> Requested Resources <rusage[no_mem_size=1:duration=1use_mem_size=2

my input file look like this.

Comment: in the first line <AL_Ptime>Interactive 
i think that is the problem.

Comment: @Lucil120 I've put these 2 lines in a file2 and called `awk -f tst.awk file2`. Works perfectly. Output: `<472971> <abce> <Lucil> <SV> <RUN> <AL_Ptime> </asdfghjk> <lsf_login07> </asdfgh>NEWLINE<456750> <dasd> <Lucil> <SV> <EXIT> <AL_Other> </asdasdasd> <lsf_login07> </csadas>`. The only thing I can image is that your jobs are not printed each on 1 line.

Comment: @Marc 
i've put these 2 lines in another file and called awk file but it's doesn't work and i don't know why @@

Comment: what's your awk version?

Comment: Ow. That's pretty old. Can you upgrade? FPAT was introduced in 4.0.

Comment: oh no i can't upgrade it. 
the company doesn't let me upgrade anything
btw thanks for your support Marc, it's help me alot.
yeah minutes ago i wonder what is FPAT